# Vim colorize edit mode

Tags: vim

I'm trying to tailor vim to my needs and I would like vim to visually indicate when it is in some kind of edit mode (insert/replace) by, for example, coloring the background red. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614546/vim-cursorline-color-change-in-insert-mode

Comment: Or this? Found in about 5 seconds of googling.  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=53

Comment: @tink - You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) plugin provides a nicely colored indicator of the current mode in the statusline: [image: http://i.imgur.com/MsuIB.png]

In addition to other useful indicators, like the current git branch.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my .vimrc
it change the background to yellow only when  I am in insert mode

```
:au InsertEnter * hi Normal term=reverse ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=yellow "
```

:au InsertLeave * hi Normal term=NONE    ctermbg=black    guibg=white "